# How can speed up search loop?

Tags: javascript

There is a cycle with the condition how can it be optimized so that the search is faster?

```
for (var i = 0; i < db.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < user.rows.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < work.length; k++) {
            if (db.rows[i].LOGIN === user.rows[j].login && work[k].name === db.rows[i].NAME) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question belongs to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs to the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site of the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically something that you would expect to see executed on the database.

That being said, you can split up the condition, so that you don't need to perform the second nested loop for every row:

```
for (var i = 0; i < db.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < user.rows.length; j++) {
        if (db.rows[i].LOGIN === user.rows[j].login) {
            for (var k = 0; k < work.length; k++) {
                if (work[k].name === db.rows[i].NAME) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly my thought, but I expected to answer the same on codereview

Answer (score 1):

You could take two [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s for the user logins and work names.

```
var userLogins = new Map(user.rows.map(o => [o.login, o])),
    workNames = new Map(o => [o.name, o]),

for (var i = 0; i < db.rows.length; i++) {
    if (userLogins.has(db.rows[i].LOGIN) && workNames.has(work[k].name)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you need just the simple check with using the objects of `user.rows` or `work`, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead.

```
var userLogins = new Set(user.rows.map(({ login } => login)),
    workNames = new Set(({ name }) => name),

for (var i = 0; i < db.rows.length; i++) {
    if (userLogins.has(db.rows[i].LOGIN) && workNames.has(work[k].name)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```